# Is it possible to pass an event as a prop together with other props in an event handler?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, properties

I'm using vue2. I have an **event handler**

```html
<textarea name="caption" :ref="`textarea-${index}`" keydown.prevent="handler(index)"></textarea>
```

When I don't pass any **prop** to the event handler, `keydown.prevent="handler"` I get the **default event** as a prop, but when I pass my own **custom prop** to the event handler  `handler(index)` I get the passed prop. This is my event handler function: `function handler(event){ console.log(event)}`  Is there a way to get both my custom prop an the default event as props in the event handler function? I have tried:
`function handler(index, event){ console.log(index, event)}` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass both parameters like this

```
<textarea name="caption" :ref="`textarea-${index}`" keydown.prevent="handler($event, index)"></textarea>
```

and get them in the function

```
function handler (event, index) { ... }
```

Comment: This solved my question. What about when you want to fire the event  in the event handler? How do you dispatch it?

Comment: You can emit a new custom event in the event handler  `function handler(event, index) { this.$emit ('myCustomEvent', event) }`